# Creating SFTP users and jailing to chroot on CentOS - user authentication error

Tags: sftp, centos6.4

I've got a CentOs release 6.4 with Digital Ocean and would like to successfully create SFTP users and jail them to the user's own chroot home directory but I fear I'm making a mess of this.

I've tried a lot of things, far too many to list here really as most is probably incorrect or won't make much sense but what I feel should be the correct process and what I have tried is:-

Create a group for `sftp`:-

```
groupadd sftp
```

Create a user and set their home directory:-

```
useradd -d /var/www/vhosts/domain.com dummyuser
```

Set a password for the user:-

```
passwd dummyuser
```

Change the user's group to 'sftp':-

```
usermod -g sftp dummyuser
```

Set the user's shell to `/bin/false`:-

```
usermod -s /bin/false dummyuser
```

Edit Subsystem in `sshd_config` (`/etc/ssh/`):-

```
#Subsystem sftp /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
```

Add the following to the bottom of the `sshd_config` file:-

```
Match group sftp
    X11Forwarding no
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I make sure all the following directories are `root:root`:-

```
/var
/var/www
/var/www/vhosts
/var/www/vhosts/domain.com
```

If I then try to log in to the server via SFTP with the user `dummyuser` (in WinSCP), I get the following:-

```
Authentication log (see session log for details):
Using username "dummyuser".

Authentication failed.
```

All I want to achieve is jailing a user to their home directory. I've also got vsftpd set up and configured. Users could log in fine but would have access to the entire server - I just haven't managed to get jailing to work at all.

## Edit

Forgot to mention, I then restarted `sshd` also:-

```
service sshd restart
```

When the error is produced in WinSCP, their help page on this is [here](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/message_unexpected_close).

## Log Results

```
/var/log/secure
```

I replaced the actual server name with `server_name`.

```
 Apr 28 14:20:56 server_name sshd[9944]: Accepted password for dummyuser from 80.194.255.4 port 44402 ssh2
 Apr 28 14:20:56 server_name sshd[9944]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user dummyuser by (uid=0)
 Apr 28 14:20:56 server_name sshd[9946]: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/vhosts/"
 Apr 28 14:20:56 server_name sshd[9944]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user dummyuser
```

Comment: Did you restart `sshd`? What is in the log files on the server?

Comment: Yes I did, sorry I forgot to add that to the end of my question (will include now). Which log file (and location) should I be looking in because I have failed to find a 'session log' file so far? Thanks.

Comment: You'll want to take a look at `/var/log/secure`.

Comment: Excellent, thank you - this helps (updating question with log entries).

Comment: fatal: bad ownership or modes for chroot directory component "/var/www/vhosts/" something such as this I suspected but `vhosts` is `root:root`.

Comment: What is the full permission on `/var/www/vhosts`? E.g. only root user should have write permissions, not everyone.

Comment: `ls -ld /var/www/vhosts` outputs `drwxrwxr-x 3 root root 4096 Oct 25  2013 vhosts` is this looking incorrect? Thanks

Comment: Nope, group is not allowed to have write permission (even if it's root group): `chmod g-w /var/www/vhosts`

Comment: @faker - legend - works perfectly. log in as `dummyuser` and now jailed to `/var/www/vhosts/domain.com` - thank you for noticing that. Will accept as answer if you want to answer.

Comment: Could you use filesystem ACLs? Give permissions to the sftp group?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a common pitfall:
All folders up to the chroot home must be owned and only writable by `root` user.
The folders cannot be group writable - even if the group is `root`.

Comment: I just learnt a trick to check this conveniently: `namei -l /var/www/vhosts`

Answer (score 5):

I found and successfully configured sftp on CentOS 6.5:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/chroot-sftp-setup/

Edit sshd config:

vim /etc/ssh/sshd_config

```
#Subsystem      sftp    /usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server (comment out the default with "#")

add:

Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftp-only
ChrootDirectory /var/www/%u
    AllowTCPForwarding no
    X11Forwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Exit and save.

Then:

```
mkdir /etc/skel2
groupadd sftp-only
getent group |grep sftp-only  (take note the GID (Group ID).  Here, in my example it's 500)
```

For a new user named "testuser" (member of the sftp-only group with GID 500):

```
useradd --base-dir /var/www --gid 500 --skel /etc/skel2 --create-home --shell /sbin/nologin testuser
```

(i use empty /etc/skel2 so no .bashrc etc is copied by default by CentOS)

```
mkdir -p /var/www/testuser/home/testuser

chown root:sftp-only /var/www/testuser
chmod 750 /var/www/testuser

chown root:root /var/www/testuser/home
chmod 755 /var/www/testuser/home

chown testuser:sftp-only /var/www/testuser/home/testuser
chmod 770 /var/www/testuser/home/testuser
```

So in this example, i made it to give secure access to external consulting firms that manage websites.  You could after creating all this do:

```
mkdir /var/www/testuser/home/testuser/www.somesite.com
chown testuser:apache /var/www/testuser/home/testuser/www.somesite.com
chmod xxx (permissions to the website as needed, usually 750 so apache would get read access)
```

One could fine tune all this as needed.

Hope this helped!

Guy Boisvert
IngTegration inc.
http://www.ingtegration.com

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: Since you changed sshd config, I'd suggest you restart it :
`service sshd restart`