# chroot and sftp: directory ownership changes unexpectedly

Tags: centos6, sftp, chroot

I have read and followed a few [questions](https://serverfault.com/questions/591781/creating-sftp-users-and-jailing-to-chroot-on-centos-user-authentication-error) and [tutorials](https://askubuntu.com/questions/49271/how-to-setup-a-sftp-server-with-users-chrooted-in-their-home-directories) on using `chroot` to set the initial directory in `sftp`. I have the correct permissions and ownership of the `chroot` directory. I can get new users to log in, but then they are unable to transfer files to folders they are supposed to own.

---

#### Example

I want to `chroot` members of the `sftpbackups` group. In my `sshd_config` file I have the following.

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match Group sftpbackups
        ChrootDirectory %h
        X11Forwarding no
        AllowTcpForwarding no
        ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

First, I have created a user `testuser` who is not added to to the `sftpbackups` group. Home directory is `/home/testuser/` and there is a subdirectory `/home/testuser/backups/` that I want to use over sftp. I can use sftp to transfer files to my `backups` folder, e.g.

```
sftp> ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    2 testuser testuser     4096 Sep 25 00:09 backups
sftp> put a.txt backups
Uploading a.txt to /home/testuser/backups/a.txt
a.txt
```

The problem comes when I add `testuser` to the `sftpbackups` group.

```
sftp> ls -l
drwxrwxrwx    2 1290     1291         4096 Sep 30 14:58 backups
sftp> put a.txt backups
Uploading a.txt to /backups/a.txt
remote open("/backups/a.txt"): Permission denied
```

I am not sure why the directory ownership is changing only after I add to the `sftpbackups` group, and I think it is related to why I cannot transfer files.

---

Any ideas how to move forward? Thanks. The server is CentOS 6.8.

Comment: obviously, SELinux ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer on a [blog](https://www.chriscowley.me.uk/blog/2012/11/19/sftp-chroot-on-centos/). We need to tell SELinux that we want to upload files via SFTP to a chroot. It is read-only by default.

```
setsebool -P ssh_chroot_rw_homedirs on
```