# Creating multiple SFTP users in Centos (installed in AWS EC2) with SELinux

Tags: amazon-ec2, centos7, sftp, selinux

I am having difficulty letting others FTP/SFTP to our site. I have multiple Virtual Name Servers created and each of them running their own website. So , I would like to give FTP/SFTP access to users.

I followed the same steps as described in this [Serverfault forum](https://serverfault.com/questions/591781/creating-sftp-users-and-jailing-to-chroot-on-centos-user-authentication-error?newreg=93261176c22c473fb3ea5eea575a40b4.ddf) question. Made sure all folder (not files) are 755 to root and made root as owner.

My Steps are as follows,

Adding a group

```
groupadd sftp
```

Created User

```
useradd -d /var/www/vivektest.com.au/public_html vivek

passwd vivek
```

Added to group and modified bin

```
usermod -g sftp vivek
usermod -s /sbin/nologin vivek
```

Modified SSHD config

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp
Match group sftp
    X11Forwarding no
    ChrootDirectory %h
    AllowTcpForwarding no
    ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

Restarted the sshd service. 
Made sure the home folder is root owned.

```
sudo ls -ld /var/www/vivektest.com.au/public_html
drwxr-xr-x. 2 root root 23 Dec 14 03:10 /var/www/vivektest.com.au/public_html
```

Again ***not the files inside***. There are other virtual server directories for different websites (like abctest.com.au, xyz.com.au) and they all have same permission settings.

I tried various other ways and followed many other suggestions but they are all failing and I don't want to break the server anymore.

The ***log file*** at /var/log/secure doesn't give me much

```
Dec 14 05:12:10 ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx sshd[3833]: error: Received disconnect from 149.135.125.62: 14: No supported authentication methods available [preauth]
```

***File Zilla*** says

```
Status: Connecting to ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com...
Response:   fzSftp started, protocol_version=7
Command:    open "vivek@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xx.ap-southeast-2.compute.amazonaws.com" 22
Error:  Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic)
Error:  Could not connect to server
```

It is a CentOS machine residing in Amazon AWS EC2.

There are other files and folder before /var/www such as httpd,logs,home which are not under root but centos (default ec2 user). Will that be a problem?

Also, I have webmin. However, when I go to SSH login module I get a message

```
There is no SSH server running on xx.xxx.xx.xx port 22.
```

I am not sure whether it has any significance to the problem I have.

Also, my **SELINUX** is Enforcing. However, I haven't made any modification to it.

It would be great, if someone could shed some light on it.

Thanks.
V

Comment: how do you want to authenticate?

Comment: Hi @Jakuje, sorry I couldn't understand your question correctly. I just want the users to use the username and password given to them to access their home directories (their website folders) and be able to read/write. Does it answer your question?